# C program not sleeping in main()

Tags: c, multithreading, sleep

I'm trying to force my program to sleep for a second after it creates a thread. I can make the thread sleep within its process but not in the main. Everything I read says it is just a system process that should work wherever it's called. I want it to sleep after printing that the thread has been created (before the join). There is no delay between the "create" and "joined and exited" print statements. Can you tell why it isn't working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SECONDS   1     //seconds to sleep
#define SIZE     25     //number of fibonaccis to be computed

int *fibResults;        //array to store fibonacci results
int  idx;               //index for the threads

//executes and exits each thread
void *run(void *param) {
  if (idx == 0) {

    sleep(SECONDS);
    fibResults[idx] = 0;
    pthread_exit(0);

  } else if (idx == 1) {

    sleep(SECONDS);   
    fibResults[idx] = 1;
    pthread_exit(0);   

  } else {

    sleep(SECONDS);
    fibResults[idx] = fibResults[idx -1] + fibResults[idx -2];
    pthread_exit(0);

  }
}


int main(void) {
  fibResults = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(*fibResults));
  pthread_attr_t attrs;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrs);

  for (idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++) {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, &attrs, run, NULL);

    printf("Thread[%d] created\t", idx);

    sleep(SECONDS); //THIS IS WHERE SLEEP ISN'T WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    printf("Thread[%d] joined & exited\t", idx);
    printf("The fibonacci of %d= %d\n", idx, fibResults[idx]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: Works on my machine.  What error are you getting/what is the behavior you're getting that makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: There is no delay between the "create" and "joined and executed" print statements.

Comment: Or use `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Did you consider trying a larger value for `SECONDS`? That would have been the very first thing I tried in order to see if the call was working or not.

Comment: fflush(stdout); works

Comment: @Technophobe01 `unistd.h` and `pthread.h` point to UNIX.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Duh, mia culpa maxima ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (idx = 0; idx < SIZE; idx++)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, &a, run, NULL);
  printf("Thread[%d] created\t", idx);
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(SECONDS);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  printf("Thread[%d] joined & exited\t", idx);
  printf("The fibonacci of %d= %d\n", idx, fibResults[idx]);
}
```